# WildFly Galleon: Web application as a feature-pack

Tags: wildfly

Does Galleon customize only the application server (WildFly) itself or allows to embed pre-deployed applications into it?
Can a web application be placed to WildFly as a feature pack?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can but currently this is a manual process to create such a feature pack.
You can take a look at https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack which creates postgresql datasource.
Not sure there is an application example currently available.